# Python string.format() percentage without rounding

Tags: python, floating-point, string.format

In the example below I would like to format to 1 decimal place but python seems to like rounding up the number, is there a way to make it not round the number up?

```
>>> '{:.1%}'.format(0.9995)
'100.0%'
>>> '{:.2%}'.format(0.9995)
'99.95%'
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to round down *always* (instead of rounding to the nearest precision), then do so, explicitly, with the [`math.floor()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.floor):

```
from math import floor

def floored_percentage(val, digits):
    val *= 10 ** (digits + 2)
    return '{1:.{0}f}%'.format(digits, floor(val) / 10 ** digits)

print floored_percentage(0.995, 1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from math import floor
>>> def floored_percentage(val, digits):
...     val *= 10 ** (digits + 2)
...     return '{1:.{0}f}%'.format(digits, floor(val) / 10 ** digits)
... 
>>> floored_percentage(0.995, 1)
'99.5%'
>>> floored_percentage(0.995, 2)
'99.50%'
>>> floored_percentage(0.99987, 2)
'99.98%'
```

Answer (score 2):

With Python 3.6+, you can use formatted string literals, also known as f-strings. These are more efficient than `str.format`. In addition, you can use more efficient floor division instead of `math.floor`. In my opinion, the syntax is also more readable.

Both methods are included below for comparison.

```
from math import floor
from random import random

def floored_percentage(val, digits):
    val *= 10 ** (digits + 2)
    return '{1:.{0}f}%'.format(digits, floor(val) / 10 ** digits)

def floored_percentage_jpp(val, digits):
    val *= 10 ** (digits + 2)
    return f'{val // digits / 10 ** digits:.{digits}f}%'

values = [random() for _ in range(10000)]

%timeit [floored_percentage(x, 1) for x in values]      # 35.7 ms per loop
%timeit [floored_percentage_jpp(x, 1) for x in values]  # 28.1 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
def my_format(num, x):
     return str(num*100)[:4 + (x-1)] + '%'

>>> my_format(.9995, 1)
'99.9%'
>>> my_format(.9995, 2)
'99.95%'
>>> my_format(.9999, 1)
'99.9%'
>>> my_format(0.99987, 2)
'99.98%'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways, maybe the easiest is

```
x = str(10. * 0.9995).split('.')
my_string = '%s.%s%%' % (x[0], x[1][:2])
```

this will ensure that you always have the decimal point in the correct place (for edge cases like `1.0000` or `0.001`)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on accepted answer while using more modern python 3.6+ f-string formatting

```
def floored_percentage(val, digits):
    val *= 10 ** (digits + 2)
    return f'{floor(val) / 10 ** digits}%)'
```

Without any digits (like I needed), it's even simpler:

```
def floored_percentage(val):
    return f"{floor(val*100)}%"
```