# Python Rounding Down to Custom Step

Tags: python, rounding

We have a partially working code and 2 examples with different types of custom steps. The example 2 (Int) is working, while the example 1 is not, as it is rounding up instead of down.

```
import math

def step_size_to_precision(ss):
    return ss.find('1') - 1

def format_value(val, step_size_str):
    precision = step_size_to_precision(step_size_str)
    if precision > 0:
        return "{:0.0{}f}".format(val, precision)
    return math.floor(int(val))


###########################

# # example 1
step_size = "0.00000100"
quantity = 0.00725562
print(quantity)
print(format_value(quantity, step_size))

# 0.00725562
# 0.007256  <= Is rounding up instead of down. Should be 0.007255 

###########################

# # example 2
# step_size = "1"
# quantity = 3.00725562
# print(quantity)
# print(format_value(quantity, step_size))

# returns 3 <= This is correct

###########################
```

How do we fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is outlined in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17610905/2402281):

> If you want to round down *always* (instead of rounding to the nearest
>   precision), then do so, explicitly, with the [`math.floor()`
>   function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.floor):
>
> ```
> from math import floor
>
> def floored_percentage(val, digits):
>     val *= 10 ** (digits + 2)
>     return '{1:.{0}f}%'.format(digits, floor(val) / 10 ** digits)
>
> print floored_percentage(0.995, 1)
>  Demo:
>
> >>> from math import floor
> >>> def floored_percentage(val, digits):
> ...     val *= 10 ** (digits + 2)
> ...     return '{1:.{0}f}%'.format(digits, floor(val) / 10 ** digits)
> ... 
> >>> floored_percentage(0.995, 1)
> '99.5%'
> >>> floored_percentage(0.995, 2)
> '99.50%'
> >>> floored_percentage(0.99987, 2)
> '99.98%'
> ```

For your example:

```
import math

def step_size_to_precision(ss):
    return max(ss.find('1'), 1) - 1

def format_value(val, step_size):
    digits = step_size_to_precision(step_size)
    val *= 10 ** digits
    return '{1:.{0}f}'.format(digits, math.floor(val) / 10 ** digits)


step_size = "0.00000100"
quantity = 0.00725562
print(quantity)
print(format_value(quantity, step_size))

# prints out: 0.007255
```

Comment: The thing is that the step_size comes in a number, not in digits amount.

Comment: Cool, now it works for example 1, but the example 2 is not working. I get: ValueError: Format specifier missing precision

Comment: Ah yes, this is mainly due to your `step_size_to_precision` function. I'll fix it for the sake of completeness!

Comment: I found an exception where AKX answer doesn't work (where stepsize = "1.0" and the quantity is for example 14.55. Returns 14.5 instead of 14) Your solution on the other hand works perfectly.. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to use `Decimal` objects to for precise decimal numbers to begin with.

Then, use [`Decimal.quantize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize) in the [`ROUND_DOWN` mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#rounding-modes).

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_DOWN

quantity = 0.00725562

step_size = Decimal("0.000001")
print(Decimal(quantity).quantize(step_size, ROUND_DOWN))
```

prints out

```
0.007255
```

Answer (score 0):

A more general approach which allows to round down for `step_size` which is not only power of 10:

```py
from decimal import Decimal

def floor_step_size(quantity, step_size):
    step_size_dec = Decimal(str(step_size))
    return float(int(Decimal(str(quantity)) / step_size_dec) * step_size_dec)
```

Usage:

```py
>>> floor_step_size(0.00725562, "0.00000100")
0.007255
>>> floor_step_size(3.00725562, "1")
3.0
>>> floor_step_size(2.6, "0.25")
2.5
>>> floor_step_size(0.9, "0.2")
0.8
```